# How to duplicate or copy data on my first Jframe table to second jframe table?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable

My problem is this. I have a table on my first JFrame and now I want the data on my first table to be duplicated on the table of my second JFrame. I'm using GUI, I have 2 JFrames, both JFrames have tables and i want both tables to display same data.

I have come up to this solution but I don't know how to set the data on my second table.

This is the code:

```
public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    TableModel dtm = table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)`enter code here`
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    return tableData;
}
```

How do I solve the problem?

To make it more clear. ill attach photo

[this is my first JFrame Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQzcB.png)

[this is my second JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k8bX.png)

my second jframe is just a summary of what is being entered in first JFrame. that is the reason why i use 2 JFrames.

i have 2 JFrame forms. in First JFrame Form i have this Code, i tried to modify the code above a bit.

```
public Object[][] getEquipTableData () {
    TableModel dtm = equipmentBorrowTable.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
     tableDataE = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableDataE[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    return tableDataE;
}
```

and then at the second JFrame i have this partof code

```
 public StudentSumarry() {
        StudentModeDashboard SMD = new StudentModeDashboard();
        String[] columnNames = {"Employee 1", "Employee 2", "Employee 3", "Employee 4"};
        Object[][] firstTableData = SMD.getEquipTableData();
        initComponents();
           equipmentBorrowTable2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(firstTableData, columnNames));
}
```

i instantiate my JFrame1 on JFrame2 to use the method getEquipTableData() on JFrame1. IDK if what im doing is right.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost take some time to read [if multiple JFrames is good or bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)

Secondly, you can change the `TableModel` of the second `JTable`, by using `setModel()` method passing a [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). The `getTableData` method you have created seems to be ok in order to achieve something like this.

```
Object[][] firstTableData = getTableData(firstTable);
secondJTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(firstTableData, columnNames));
```

(After some comments taking place):

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
public class JTables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame 1");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JTable table = new JTable(randomData(), new String[] { "FirstTableCol1", "FirstTableCol2" });

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JTable table2 = new JTable(randomData(), new String[] { "SecondTableCol1", "SecondTableCol2" });

            frame2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame2.add(new JScrollPane(table2));

            JButton button = new JButton("copy");
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                Object[][] data = getTableData(table);
                table2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[] { "SecondTableCol1", "SecondTableCol2" }));
            });
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame2.pack();
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static Object[][] randomData() {
        Object arr[][] = new Object[5][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i][0] = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 10000));
            arr[i][1] = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 10000));
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static Object[][] getTableData(JTable table) {
        TableModel dtm = table.getModel();
        int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
        Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
                tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i, j);
        return tableData;
    }

}
```

Comment: [George Zorwell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpkHo.png) I presume? (Sorry, silly pun based on your current rep. being the title of a famous book.)

Comment: i doesnt display the data on table2 bro. i updated the question please take a look at the pictures i attached.

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda Without giving us your code or a [mcve] to see how exactly you create each `JTable` we really cannot help you. The code works fine for me.

Comment: Object[][] firstTableData = getTableData(firstTable);
secondJTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(firstTableData, columnNames));

This solution works if both tables are on the same JFrame. My goal is to copy the data of my Table1 on JFrame1 to  Table2 of JFrame2

Comment: I created my table in Netbeans by GUI Drag and Drop. JTable.

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda Then you have one more reason to avoid using a second JFrame. However, give me some time to check it myself.

Comment: allright bro. thank you . update me bro if you found a solution for it. thanks!

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda Check my example. It works fine. With 2 JFrames. I will mention again that you should post a [mcve] or more parts of your code. There might be one million reasons why this does not work for you (i mean in your main application).

Comment: @George Z. hey bro thanks. ive tried your code and its working. Have you checked the pictures i attached bro? I have 2 JFrame Forms there and the table 1 is one the first JFrame Form while table2 is on second JFrame form, Jframe form 1 and 2 have different source file bro soo thats why i have difficulty linking both tables.

Comment: hey bro. i added some info on my question.

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda In the screenshots you have posted, the data seems pretty copied to me..

Comment: @George Z i didnt put any value on table1 bro which is the first screenshot . i want the value on table1 to be copied also in my table2 on JFrame2. i copied table1 thats why they look the same bro.

Comment: @CharlieMagneAguda Sorry i can't help you more without a [mcve].